# Generating multiple bar plots in multiple columns concurrently in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

Data are as follows:

```
df<-read.table(text=" A1 A2 A3  M1 M2 M3 
F   M   F   A   B   A
M   M   F   A   B   A
F   M   F   A   B   A
F   M   F   C   B   A
F   M   F   C   B   A
M   M   F   C   C   B
F   M   F   C   C   B
M   F   F   C   C   B
F   F   F   D   C   B
M   F   F   D   C   B
F   F   F   D   A   B
F   F   F   D   A   C
F   F   F   D   A   C
M   F   F   D   A   C
F   M   M   B   A   D
F   M   M   B   A   D
F   M   M   B   D   D
M   M   M   B   D   D
F   M   M   B   D   D ", h=T)
```

I want to have bar plots for A1 with M1; A2 with M2 and A3 with M3. So far I've tried:

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
map2(names(df)[4:6], names(df)[1:3], ~
ggplot(df, aes(x = !!rlang::sym(.x), y = !!rlang::sym(.y))) + 
geom_bar())
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

I struggled to fix the error. Any help?

I want to have this for each plot:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x = A1, fill = M1)) +
 geom_bar(position = position_dodge())
```

Comment: Use `geom_col` not `geom_bar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining both the working example and what was tried, did you want:

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

map2(names(df)[1:3], names(df)[4:6], ~
       ggplot(df, aes_string(x = .x, fill = .y)) + 
       geom_bar(position = position_dodge()))
```

It looks like you want `fill` for columns 4-6 (M1, M2, and M3) - is that correct? You did not need `y` in `aes` then, just `fill`.

Also, you can make use of `aes_string` instead of `rlang::sym`.

Finally, added `position_dodge` based on your working example. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.